# How can i expose pattern for a user to link two accounts together in Azure ACS and WIF (SWT tokens)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, wif

Right now when the user is authenticated (over Azure ACS with WIF enabled for SWT tokens) it dont look like I can let them sign in again with a new provider and get two tokens.

im looking for a pattern that would let users link two accounts together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Identity Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185971.aspx), you get a unique "Name Identifier" per provider. You would have to manually link them together by storing them in a repository.

e.g.

- User logs in via Facebook. Store the identifier.
- Ask user if they want to use other providers.
- User logs in via Google. Link the identifier to the Facebook one.

**Update:**

You need to have a "control" identity e.g. something like the normal SQL membership provider. So firstly they log in as this identity. Then you have a workflow that asks "Would you like to use another identity?" You know their control identity so you map the new "name identifier" to the control identity. If they log in with one of the ACS identities, you search your repository. If you don't find it. you say "We haven't seen this identity before. Please log in as your control and then map it".

Comment: Thats how i was planning to do it also, but it do not look like Azure ACS let the user log on again to another provider if already logged in. Also, dont i need some kind of validation that the user is the same. User logs out and in with another provider, how can i be sure its not just some other user who logs in.

Comment: I am missing one little part to get this to work. When the user are logged on as one identity, i do know his name identifier. Problem is how do i securely create the workflow that he wants to link another identity. As soon he press login to another STS, i got no reference to what identity he had before. (Should i save a unique guid in a cookie?, would it be better to let him type in the mail and then he needs to confirm the link from both accounts?)

Comment: I would store the control id in the session or in a cookie. Then take the new identity and map it to the control.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain a little bit more. Is this a website? (assume yes, as you tagged the question as "MVC"). Which providers are you using? (e.g. FB, LiveID, Google, your own). How is your app identifying users? (e.g. unique handle, e-mail address, etc).

The token you get is always from ACS and it's independent of the providers. You can actually use ACS to normalize the information from all different providers into something common. Thus "linking" the two of them. You do this with ACS transformation rules.

If you use "passthrough" rules then you get whatever the IdPs give you, and the association would have to happen at the app.

Comment: I use FB, LiveID, Google and Yahoo. You are on the right track - its all from ACS. I have the nameidentifiers for each user. My problem is more of how I can do the linking. Because i need the tokens/claims from two providers at the same time i assume. It would not be a good way to ask the user to logof and on with the other one and hope he get matched up with his own id. My problem was that i was not able to login from ACS at the same time with two providers, if i try to do so, i just get send back with the identity that i got in the first place again.